# Return Type of an Immediate await vs Postponed await

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, async-await

I am seeking clarification as to why an immediate `await` returns the type of the asynchronous, non-void task whereas postponing the `await` returns the task itself. If my terminology in the title or elsewhere is incorrect, please let me know.

```
private async Task<string> GetUserId(Guid id)
{
   string thisUserId = null;
   ... do stuff ...
   return thisUserId;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> MyFunc(Guid id)
{
   var a = await GetUserId(id);
   var b = GetUserId(id);
   ... do stuff ...
   await b;

   return Ok(true);
}
```

Why is `a` of type `string` while `b` is of type `Task<string>`?

Comment: The result of awaiting an expression of type `Task<T>` is always a `T`. In one case you combined calling a method with awaiting in a single statement and in another you did those in two separate statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases, your method is always returning an object of type `Task<string>`. However, when you perform the `await`, the result of that is the result of the `Task`, which is your string.

So, if you do that when you originally call the method, you're processing the `Task` immediately. However with your second call, you don't process the `Task` until after you "do stuff". In that case, your variable is still the `Task` that will return the string. Once you finally call `await` on it, then you get the result of that task.